# Clear certain criteria from .viminfo file

Tags: vim

How can I clear certain criteria from my .viminfo file?

I want to clear the command line history, file marks, jumplist, etc.

***However***, I want to keep the search string history.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: This should be migrated to SuperUser.com, since it's not directly about programming.

Comment: I'd vote to reopen if I could. This is exactly what I needed to know right now for my programming needs. See http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25925/vim-questions-do-they-belong-to-stack-overflow-or-super-user

Comment: I do not think this is off-topic.  The editor vim is a "software tool commonly used by programmers" (and thus is in scope).  It is certainly not a general text editor designed to be used by normal users.

Comment: I agree with CJ this relates to a tool that is *heavily* used by programmers and as such deserves to live here.

Answer (score 33):

I can think of 3 ways to do this.

## 1. Automatically

1. Run Vim,
2. Type: `:set viminfo='0,:0,<0,@0,f0`

   - `'0` means that marks will not be saved
   - `:0` means that command-line history will not be saved
   - `<0` means that registers will not be saved
   - `@0` means that input-line history will not be saved
   - `f0` means that marks will not be saved
   - no `%` means that the buffer list will not be saved
   - no `/` means that the search history *will* be saved

   These options are correct in Vim 7.2, but might be different in other versions. For more details on the format of the viminfo string, run `:h 'viminfo'`
3. Quit Vim. It will save a new version of the .viminfo file, containing only the information you want to keep.

## 2. Manually

1. Open the .viminfo file in vim,
2. `:set viminfo=` to turn off the auto-saving of info to the .viminfo file. If you don't do this, Vim will overwrite all your changes when you quit,
3. Remove everything you don't want (perhaps by using [Johnsyweb's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816719/clear-the-viminfo-file/2887380#2887380), or just by deleting the lines with manual edit commands), save the file, and quit vim,

## 3. In a different editor

Edit the .viminfo file in a *different* text editor and simply delete everything you don't want,

Answer (score 11):

Open the `.viminfo` file.

The following command will remove all lines that are neither blank, comment nor search history:

```
:v/^\([#/?]\|$\)/d
```

[@Rich's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2833376/78845) will help you prevent these lines being repopulated.

Answer (score 8):

You can use `vim` itself to modify the file, and your changes will stay put if you invoke it like this:

```
$ vim -i NONE ~/.viminfo
```

Starting `vim` with the `-i` option sets which `viminfo` file to use for that session. The special value `NONE` means that nothing is saved at all. This can be handy for editing other auto-generating files or sensitive data.

From `man vim`:

> `-i {viminfo}`
>   When using the *viminfo* file is enabled, this option sets the  *filename*
>   to use, instead of the default `~/.viminfo`.  This can also be used to
>   skip the use of the *viminfo* file, by giving the name `NONE`.

Answer (score 3):

VIM seems not having a built-in command for this job. But you can do it in a shell with "grep". 
For example, the following command will clear the Command Line History,File marks, Jumplist:

```
bash $ grep -v "^[:'-]" .viminfo > .viminfo_clear
bash $ cp .viminfo_clear .viminfo
```

If you open the .viminfo, you will find that the command line history is started with ":", the file mark is started with "'", and the jumplist is started with "-".

Comment: eeeeeeeeeeeeee... bad answer.
why you are creating unnecessary file and your answer is wrong.

Answer (score 2):

Copy useful part out and delete .viminfo, then open/close Vim. It will regenerate .viminfo. Then copy useful part back.