# How to clear vim `oldfiles`?

Tags: file, vim

Vim's `:oldfiles` command shows the last 100 open files. I want to clear this list. How do I do that?

I tried googling for "vim oldfiles clear" but that doesnt return useful results.  I also tried googling "vim oldfiles location" but also nothing.

Comment: I don't know the answer, nor did I know this was a Vim feature, but what is the desired reason for clearing this list?

Comment: you may want to look at [clearing the .viminfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2816719/clear-the-viminfo-file) question but that's assuming you want to remove everything in the file (including other marks)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

This command basically lists the  contents of the `v:oldfiles` variable.
However, emptying  the variable is not  what you want, because  it is by
itself generated from the contents of the *.viminfo* file.

Please read  the help for `viminfo`.  Vim won't store a  list of "recent
files". Those files  come from the saved marks. And  *.viminfo* stores a
lot of things. I'm not sure you want  to remove all of them, so you need
to edit  that portion of file.  Editing it, however, can  be a difficult
maneuver —  if  you  don't  disable auto  saving it will  overwrite when
quitting.

The best  solution to  your case, in  my opinion, is  to change  the Vim
setting that  stores recent file marks  to store nothing; and  then tell
Vim to rewrite the file. This can be achieved by the following commands.
Please do  this in  a newly  opened Vim session,  ideally, one  that you
haven't edited a file yet.

```
:set vi+='0  " save no marks, in other words save 0 recent marks
:wv!         " write viminfo file without merging with old information
```

Reload  Vim and  your list  should be  clean. Please  read the  help for
`'vi'` to  known more. If  you want the recent  files list to  be always
empty,  you may  want to  configure  that option  to your  will in  your
*.vimrc*.  It is also  useful  to see  your current  configuration  with
`:set vi`.